# Need a new method in CatalogEndpoint: findAllProductsForCategory

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I have REST API working, but I need a way to return all products within a certain category.  Right now I'm using **findSearchResultsByCategoryAndQuery** by passing the category id and using a *very* generic query to get almost all the products in the category.  What I really need is a method called findAllProductsForCategory which returns all products in the category.

I'm new to Broadleaf and REST API, can someone please guide me through how to extend CatalogEndpoint to get the functionality I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Althought broadleaf provides SQL injection protection (ExploitProtectionServiceImpl) I recommend you to use ProductDao.

- Extend org.broadleafcommerce.core.web.api.endpoint.catalog.CatalogEndpoint or add in your implementation new method that utilize ProductDao

```spring
@Resource("blProductDao")
private ProductDao productDao;

@RequestMapping(value = "search/products-by-category/{categoryId}") //GET is by default
public List<Product> findSearchResultsByCategory(HttpServletRequest request, @PathVariable("categoryId") Long categoryId {
    return productDao.readProductsByCategory(categoryId);
}
```

- It's querying database with:

```sql
SELECT categoryProduct.product_id 
FROM BLC_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_XREF categoryProduct
WHERE categoryProduct.category_id = :categoryId
ORDER BY COALESCE (categoryProduct.display_order,999999)
```

- Or if you want to create your own dao

```spring
public class MyProductDaoImpl extends ProductDaoImpl implements MyProductDao {

    public static final String QUERY = "SELECT categoryProduct.product_id " +
            "FROM BLC_CATEGORY_PRODUCT_XREF categoryProduct " +
            "WHERE categoryProduct.category_id = :categoryId";

    @Override
    public List<Product> meFindingProductsByCategory(String categoryId) {
        Query query = em.createQuery(QUERY);
        query.setParameter("categoryId", categoryId);
        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

- You can choose if you are producing JSON or XML. Be sure that you have coresponding Product model for binding results